# how to use reportservice2005.asmx

Tags: sql, sql-server, service, reporting

is there an article that explain how to implement reportservice2005.asmx?

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN section on [Reporting Services Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155076%28SQL.90%29.aspx) is a great place to start...but in particular, the [Report Server Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) sub-section is what you are after...

Comment: thanks for the links.. but I need an article that has a working sample code (something like in codeproject where you can download the sample app).

Comment: what do you want to do with the reporting services api?

Comment: I need to have client app implements reportviewer with accessing reporting service via WCF. not sure if this is possible.

Comment: do you want to access the Reports via WCF or do you want reports to access data via WCF? sorry!

Comment: I need the WCF to access the report and pass it on to client.. The idea is client will only know Server1 and not Server2 (where the SQL server and reporting service are sitting)